# In RSA encryption algorithm, Can we find P ,Q and totient of N if we have N value?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, calculation

N is p*q while totient(N) is a product of (p-1)(q-1) and (P-1),(Q-1) will not be prime after taken 1 from them. For an example N is 51. 51 = p*q while Totient(N) is a product of pq -p -q + 1. So the totient(N) = 51-p-q+1. What should I do after this? How to get p,q from N value (RSA)?

Comment: Note: in text in Stack posts asterisk is used as markdown for italic, or if doubled for bold. To use an actual asterisk character you must backslash it. I fixed for you, but in future please proofread your posts to make sure they render correctly. (In *code* marked by backticks, or blocks with 4-space indentation or triple backticks, asterisk is treated as data. Note that I wrote *code* in itialics by actually writing \*code\*.)

Answer (score 0):

The only analytic (non-implementation) way of obtaining p,q from n is to factor n. For a toy value like 51, this is easy; just try possible values of p until you find p=3 q=17 (or swap to p=17 q=3 if you like). For the sizes of n used in practice -- until a few years ago usually 1024 bits which is about 308 decimal digits, now at least 2048 bits (616 digits) and sometimes more -- there is no known way to factor in less than thousands of years, and that is why RSA is considered generically secure, because knowing p,q enables you to trivially recover the private exponent and decrypt and/or forge data.

Particular implementations sometimes choose the RSA primes badly when generating keys, or leak information about them through side channels, or leak information about the resulting private exponent (d). These attacks are specific to an implementation, and depend on a lot of details and a much higher level of knowledge than exhibited in your question. Knowing d plus the public key allows you to compute p,q; this has been asked and answered many times on other stacks which I'll dig up later. Note that your question is really about the mathematics behind RSA not any program code or language(s), although if there were a method it could well be embodied in code, so it is less suitable here and would be more suitable (but trivial or duplicate) on https://crypto.stackexchange.com or https://security.stackexchange.com .

It is believed that if and when research into quantum computers is successful they will be vastly more efficient at factoring, enough to make RSA insecure. If and when this happens you can expect to see it on every news channel and site in the world.